# lalongooo/VideoCompressor: Audio is missing in compressed video?

Tags: android, android-studio, video-processing, video-compression

[*Video Compression Sample*](https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor)
The video compression process is complete successfully. But the compressed video lost its audio.

This question is already answer in GitHub issue.
[The voice disappear after compression](https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor/issues/38). And answer is to add dependencies like this.

```
implementation (group: 'com.googlecode.mp4parser', name: 'isoparser', version: '1.0.6') {force = true}
```

But this not resolve the audio problem

what i had tried

```
{
    compile 'life.knowledge4:k4l-video-trimmer:1.0'
    compile 'org.mp4parser:isoparser:1.9.27'
}
```

Runtime error

```
Error: Program type already present: org.mp4parser.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.ajcDeclarePrecedence
```

Full Description

```
Program type already present: org.mp4parser.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.ajcDeclarePrecedence
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: org.mp4parser.aspectj.internal.lang.annotation.ajcDeclarePrecedence
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: wait i will post

Comment: compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'

Comment: Sure, Thanks, Vora!

Comment: I am getting this error Duplicate class org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.UnlockSignatureImpl found in modules jetified-aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar (aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar) and jetified-aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.2)

Comment: Remove older version first than add this dependency

Comment: after trying many hours finally I found something good. see here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250344/6925888

Answer (score 0):

I tried this `SiliCompressor` for video compressor, which is very well,
and in this version Audio and Video working well.

https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor/tree/v2.2.2